# ftp user creates file on server which cannot be seen from the web

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I have ubuntu server with vsftpd on it.
Then I binded one folder from var/www/ to my home/ftp_user

I've entered ftp_user to www-data group.

folder has www-data rights, index.php can be seen by appache , when I open it through browser.

Now with dreamweaver I've made new file and it succesfully saved it on server. But the problem is that file has only ftp_users read and write rights. User Group www-data's rights are NONE

Despite the fact that ftp_user belongs to www-data group.
And now I cannot see this file on the web.

What can I do to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the umask is wrong (it's controls the default file permissions). Try setting it to 022.

Search for the term 'umask' on http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html

Comment: Thanks that helped, now others and www-data can read this file